# tuples in a list finding common elements

Tags: python, tuples

Let's assume I have a list that can contain a number of tuples (it will vary), such as:

```
[(ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, elle5, ele6, ele7),
(ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, elle5, ele6, ele7),
(ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, elle5, ele6, ele7),
(ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, elle5, ele6, ele7),
(ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, elle5, ele6, ele7),
etc..]
```

I want to find the tuples where `ele1`, `ele3`, `ele4` are the same but `ele6` is different)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, unfortunately i did not explain this well, apologies, i want to compare elements across tuples, for example


[
    ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'z','h'),
    ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','h'),
    ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','h'),
    ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','h'),
]

it should return
[
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'z','h')
]
as this tuple has elements 1, 3 and 4 the same as the others in the list but element 6 different

Answer (score 1):

```
for elm in your_tuple:
        if elm[0] == elm[2] == elm[3] != elm[5]: 
            print(elm)
```